# Devices connected in WLAN and Ethernet cant ping each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, ping

I have a Netgear R6220 Router. I have connected a laptop through Ethernet. It's IP Config is

```
IP : 192.168.1.3
Subnet : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 192.168.1.1
DNS : 192.168.1.1 , 8.8.8.8
```

I also have another laptop connected through Wireless LAN. It's IP Config is

```
IP : 192.168.1.7
Subnet : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 192.168.1.1
DNS : 192.168.1.1 , 8.8.8.8
```

Both devices has Internet access. The problem is both can't ping or get connected each other.

The device on the Ethernet runs a HTTP Server. I want to access it through WLAN. The ethernet device can ping successfully to Gateway IP but can't ping to WLAN device. At the same time, WLAN device neither can't ping to Gateway nor the Ethernet Device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bridge the WLAN AP interface to the Ethernet interface on your router, or to tick the appropriate box in the router's UI that does that for you.